# What does BM stand for in Gaming?

Tags: terminology

I keep seeing a phrase like "BM fatigue" in hearthstone stream chats in twich.
The context is that the streamer's opponent dies from fatigue and the whole chat says that phrase... So what does BM stand for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Hearthstone, along with most online competitive games, it usually stands for "Bad Manners".

Basically, it means someone is spamming taunts, being a bad sport, or drawing out a game when they can either win or concede just to prolong the game unnecessarily because they're salty[upset] about a loss or want to toy with their opponent a little longer before they win.

Without seeing the game you're referring to, I can only assume the opponent had no chance of winning and let himself die to fatigue just to deny the streamer the "final blow" rather than just leaving the game.

Comment: That makes sense.... I should have thought of that haha. But almost like any other internet slang people tend to use it way to often even if (in my case) it is a BIT out of context.

Comment: Yeah, if you check the edit history on my post you can see another unfortunate meaning of BM fatigue, but I put it there as a joke and knew you were talking about bad manners =) glad to help!